# How much data can be stored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I am just a beginner in MySQL, I need to know how much data can be stored in MySQL. I am developing a web crawler, can I store all the data in MySQL, or do I need to use another Database? Which is more faster? What I mean is, which has the highest Writing/Reading Rate? Do I need to reconfigure to add more data?

Comment: You mean the entire data of the web? :)

Comment: You can store as much data in MySQL as you have disk space and your OS can cope with. There's really not a lot of advice anyone can provide, given so vague information.

Comment: @Daniel :yep @MarkJ:why?

Comment: @Tom Gullen sure it is(given the OS can account for all the disk space), you might not be able to store it all in one thable though.

Comment: @Nos, you edited your comment and it is now correct.  What you said previously however was not!  :-)

Comment: A _very_ large amount can be stored in MySQL, but please keep in mind: unless you're very interested in some semantics of HTML-use, don't store actual HTML pages, store the stripped text-content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on the operating system.

```
**Operating System**           **File-size Limit**
Win32 w/ FAT/FAT32              2GB/4GB
Win32 w/ NTFS              2TB (possibly larger)
Linux 2.2-Intel 32-bit      2GB (LFS: 4GB)
Linux 2.4+                      4TB
Solaris 9/10              16TB
MacOS X w/ HFS+              2TB
NetWare w/NSS file system      8TB
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html

Your write/read rate is of pretty much no concern to you, your bottleneck is going to be your internet connection.

Comment: i am using a win32/NTFS system,what will i do if the data goes higher than 4tb??its already 3TB

Comment: Find a different DBS, SQL server on a 64bit machine can have 16TB.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx  Just shop around and see what tickles your onion jar.  Oracle can handle 8589541376 G on a 'BFT' addressing scheme.  I don't think MYSql was designed with your needs in mind.

Comment: @Tom Gullen: So you are suggesting SQL Server,is there any Open Source DB for my needs?what DB did google using?

Comment: @Alex: google is using homegrown BigTable (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362956/what-database-does-google-use).

Comment: @Wrikken : Thks for the info,in my case what all DB can use?what are the solutions? what about Hadoop?is it a DB,can i use that for a webcrawler?

Comment: .. and the MySQL manual actually suggests some solutions for a bigger table, you could just employ one of those.

Comment: @Wrikken:what are they?can you please say?

Comment: @Alex:they are at the link Tom provided. And as far as recommendation: I'd store the crawled files as documents & let sphinx (http://www.sphinxsearch.com/) index them, I do however not know about its size limits, but you can distribute them over several nodes.

Comment: @Tom : Can i use Hadoop as a DB?

Comment: i see a contradiction in the same page
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,379547,381106
says 32 TO per table
can you explain

Answer (score 0):

https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,379547,381106

InnoDB Size Limits

- Max # of tables: 4 G
- Max size of a table: 32TB
- Columns per table: 1000
- Max row size: n*4 GB
- 8 kB if stored on the same page
- n*4 GB with n BLOBs
- Max key length: 3500
- Maximum tablespace size: 64TB
- Max # of concurrent trxs: 1023

Nanda Kishore Toomula

Sr DBA,Nokia India

CMDBA 5.0

Comment: what is the max total size please